# Fix missing HTML tags using Greasemonkey userscript

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

I need to open a web page that is somehow missing `<html>...</html>`. That is, the page content is only:

```
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body>
 ...
</body>
```

without the enclosing HTML tags.

Firefox is willing to render this page, but not Chrome. I want to use userscript to fix it.

But since head and body has no parent, I can't insert anything before&after them.

Any idea how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Missing `<html>` tags would not cause this; something else is going on.  **Link to the page. Or provide enough code to duplicate the problem.**

Comment: It is reproducible using this, saved as test.xhtml:
<head>
   <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Hello</p>
</body>

Comment: a file *test.xhtml* with: `<head> <title>Foo</title> </head> <body> <p>Hello</p> </body>` doesn't work in Firefox either.  It's invalid xhtml and Firefox says so. "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element".   Chrome gives a similar error.

Comment: And that is very specifically an XML/XHTML problem (the document is not well formed), not an HTML problem (where the start and end tag for the HTML element is explicitly optionally).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will solve your issue or not. Please try this using jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(html){
       html = '<html>' + html + '</html>';
});
```

where html is the page without html tags.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/9JN3j/).